# stream_socket_client fails on some servers

Tags: php, sockets, streaming

I have a vps with direct admin panel

and a web host with cpanel and litespeed.

I tested this code:

```
$errno = 0;
$errstr = '';
$fp = @stream_socket_client('uploaded.net:80', $errno, $errstr, 20, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT);
```

on both servers.

in vps server it works successfully but in web host server it fails with connection timeout.

after connection timeout values of my variables were these:

```
$errno = 110;
$errstr = 'Connection timed out';
```

now when I tested this code :

```
$errno = 0;
$errstr = '';
$fp = @stream_socket_client('mihandownload.com:80', $errno, $errstr, 20, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT);
```

it works successfully On both servers!!

but why ?? :((

Comment: BTW, the `@` symbol is the [suppress errors operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'd check the firewalls and test that I can connect with my browser and `wget`...